# Java 8-puzzle Depth first search issue with children nodes

Tags: java, search, depth

I am creating a depth first search algorithm which will ultimately be able to solve a simple 8 puzzle. I am able to read in a file and a goal state and set these variables accordingly.

The main issue i am receiving is that when i get the children of the current node being evaluated, i am getting 2 "empty" values in my 8 puzzle, and i am also getting an index out of bounds exception.

In order to get a child node for a given parent, i first must make a valid move then update the state of the child node to reflect the results of the valid move.

In order to perform a move, i check if it is do-able(if i move left will it still be within the bounds of the puzzle), see posted code.

It functions correctly for the first 2 moves, left and down as it correctly print the expected result.

Below is the output of my current codes execution, you can see it correctly moves left and down, then it starts encountering errors.

```
 Start state:
 120
 345
 678

 after moving left
 102
 345
 678

 Parent: [[C@1b845568
 after moving down
 125
 340
 678

 Parent: [[C@d032cf5
 after moving left
 102
 340
 678

 Parent: [[C@d032cf5
 after moving down
 125
 348
 670

 Parent:
 125
 340
 678

 after moving up
 125
 348
 670

 Parent: [[C@4b7c8f7f
 after moving left
 125
 304
 670

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at dcs.aber.ac.uk.puzzle.PuzzleBoard.swapValues(PuzzleBoard.java:193)
 at dcs.aber.ac.uk.puzzle.PuzzleBoard.moveUp(PuzzleBoard.java:142)
 at dcs.aber.ac.uk.puzzle.DFSSolver.addChildren(DFSSolver.java:155)
 at dcs.aber.ac.uk.puzzle.DFSSolver.search(DFSSolver.java:85)
 at dcs.aber.ac.uk.puzzle.DFSSolver.<init>(DFSSolver.java:27)
     at dcs.aber.ac.uk.puzzle.Driver.main(Driver.java:86)
```

As you can see, after the first two the rest of the printed states are incorrect. I will post my code to show how i handle the swapping and updating of the board to see if you can identify where the complication arises.

```
    public class Node  {



private Node parent;
private char[][] state = new char[3][3];
private double cost; 
private double heurCost; 
private double funcCost; 
private int depth;

public Node() {
    parent = null;
    }

public Node(Node parent) {
    this.parent = parent;

     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< 3; j++){
            state[i][j] = parent.getState()[i][j];

        }   

    } 
} 


public void setParent(Node parent) {

    this.parent = parent;


 }


public char[][] getState() {

    return state;
}

public char[][] copyState(){
    char[][] a = new char[3][3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j< 3; j++){
             a[i][j] = state[i][j];

        }    

    } 

 return a;
}

 } 

 public class PuzzleBoard {

private  char[][] goalState;
private char[][] currentBoard;
private int emptyRow, emptyCol;
private int outOfPlace;

public PuzzleBoard(char[][] currentState, char[][] goal ){


    this.setCurrentState(currentState);
    this.setGoalState(goal);
    trackEmptySqaure();

}

public void setGoalState(char[][] goalState){

    this.goalState = goalState;

}


public void setCurrentState(char[][] currentState){

    this.currentBoard = currentState;

}



public char[][] getCurrentBoard() {

    return currentBoard;

}

public boolean checkIsGoal(char[][] board){

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j ++){
            if(!(goalState[i][j] != (board[i][j]))){

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void trackEmptySqaure() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j ++){
            if(currentBoard[i][j] == '0'){
                emptyCol = j;
                emptyRow = i;
            }

        }
    }

}

public int getemptyRow() {
    return emptyRow;

}

public int getemptyCol() {
    return emptyCol;

}



public Node moveLeft(Node parent){
    currentBoard = parent.copyState();

    Node result = new Node(parent);

    /* check you can move 'empty' left one space*/
    if(getemptyCol()  > 0){


        swapValues(result.getState(),emptyRow, emptyCol, 1);


        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
public Node moveDown(Node parent){
    currentBoard = parent.copyState();

    Node result = new Node(parent);

    /* check you can move 'empty' down one space*/
    if(getemptyRow()  < 2){


        swapValues(result.getState(),emptyRow, emptyCol,2);

        return result;
    }

    return null;
}

public Node moveUp(Node parent){
    currentBoard = parent.getState();
    Node result = new Node(parent);


    /* check you can move 'empty' up one space*/
    if(getemptyRow() > 0){


        swapValues(result.getState(),emptyRow, emptyCol,2);



        return result;
    }

    return null;
}

public Node moveRight(Node parent){
    currentBoard = parent.getState();
    Node result = new Node(parent);


    /* check you can move 'empty' right one space*/
    if(getemptyCol()  < 2){


        swapValues(result.getState(),emptyRow, emptyCol,2);



        return result;
    }

    return null;
}

   public void swapValues (char[][] c,int x, int y, int method){

    char empty = '0';
    char swapValue = '0'; // should never be kept as 0

    if(method == 1){ // left

        swapValue= c[emptyRow][emptyCol -1];
        c[emptyRow][emptyCol] = swapValue;
        c[emptyRow][emptyCol -1] = empty;
        trackEmptySqaure();


    }
    else if(method == 2){ // down

        swapValue = c[emptyRow + 1][emptyCol];
        c[emptyRow][emptyCol] = swapValue;
        c[emptyRow + 1][emptyCol] = empty;
        trackEmptySqaure();


    }
    else if(method == 3){ // up
        swapValue = c[emptyRow -1][emptyCol];
        c[emptyRow][emptyCol] = swapValue;
        c[emptyRow -1][emptyCol] = empty;
        trackEmptySqaure();


    }
    else if(method == 4){// right
        swapValue = c[emptyRow][emptyCol + 1];
        c[emptyRow][emptyCol] = swapValue;
        c[emptyRow ][emptyCol + 1] = empty;
        trackEmptySqaure();


    }




}
public class DFSSolver {

private ArrayList<Node> closed = new ArrayList<Node>();

private Stack<Node> open = new Stack<Node>();

private PuzzleBoard pb;

private boolean solved;

private int numberOfSteps;

public DFSSolver(PuzzleBoard puzzle) {

    pb = puzzle;
    numberOfSteps = 0;
    solved = false;
    Node root = new Node();
    root.setState(pb.getCurrentBoard());
    addToOpen(root);
    checkIfSolved(root);
    search();

}

public boolean inOpenList(Node n){

    for(Node node: open){
        if(node.equals(n)){
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;

}

public boolean inClosedList(Node n){

    for(Node node: closed){
        if(node.equals(n)){
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;

}


public void addToOpen(Node n){
    open.push(n);
}

public void addToClosed(Node n){
    closed.add(n);

}

public Node popOpen(){
    return open.pop();
}

public void removeFromClosed(Node n){

    closed.remove(n);

}



public void search(){

    while(!solved){

        Node current = popOpen();
        if(current != null){
            if(!(inClosedList(current))){ // is it previously explored?
                checkIfSolved(current);
                addChildren(current);
                numberOfSteps++;

            }

            addToClosed(current);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No of steps: " + numberOfSteps);
}

public void checkIfSolved(Node curr) {
    char[][] goal = pb.getGoal();
    char[][] current = curr.getState();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j ++){
            char c = current[i][j];
            char x = goal[i][j];
            if(c != x){
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    solved = true;
}


public void addChildren(Node parent){


    Node newNode = new Node(parent);



    newNode = pb.moveLeft(parent);

    if(newNode != null){
        System.out.println("Parent: " + parent.getState().toString());
        System.out.println("atfer moving left");
        System.out.println(newNode.toString());
        addToOpen(newNode);


    }

    newNode = pb.moveDown(parent);

    if(newNode != null){
        System.out.println("Parent: " + parent.getState().toString());
        System.out.println("atfer moving down");
        System.out.println(newNode.toString());
        addToOpen(newNode);


    }


    newNode = pb.moveRight(parent);

    if(newNode != null){
        System.out.println("Parent: " + parent.getState().toString());
        System.out.println("atfer moving right");
        System.out.println(newNode.toString());
        addToOpen(newNode);


    }


    newNode = pb.moveUp(parent);

    if(newNode != null){
        System.out.println("Parent:\n " + parent.toString());
        System.out.println("atfer moving up");
        System.out.println(newNode.toString());
        addToOpen(newNode);


    }
}
```

Comment: i can't find your `swapValues` method...

Comment: @EugenHalca sorry about that, i have updated the source code.

Comment: Use the debugger in your IDE to examine the values of the variables and you will certainly find out the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `move up` method you call `swap values` like this :

`swapValues(result.getState(),emptyRow, emptyCol,2);`

but i guess it should be :

`swapValues(result.getState(),emptyRow, emptyCol,3);`

also you'll want to call :

`swapValues(result.getState(),emptyRow, emptyCol,4);`

in your `moveRight` method

Comment: Thanks that solved the index out of bound exception, complete error on my part forgot to edit the values after copy and paste ahah! but i still have the same output error with it displaying 2 '0' values. guess me and the debugger have a date tonight!

Comment: @chrisedwards i want to add that your algorithm in most cases will never stop running, because you check node's that are already checked once, so change `open` variable from `Stack` to `Set` and implement `equals` method properly in `Node` class...

Comment: i appreciate the advice but the specification requires the use of the Stack Class.

Comment: you can use `Stack` if it's a requirement, just be sure you don't process the same `Node` twice

Comment: Thanks, i understand my error in that regard, still don't understand why it adds two '0' values in the board on its second run through. Currently trying to solve it using the de bugger, but its not going too well!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the other problem you reported is because the code's notion of where the empty square is doesn't always match the node you are currently processing. You call trackEmptySquare after each swap, but a better place would be to call it at *before* moveLeft, moveRight, etc., so that it will match the node you are currently looking at.

But the better approach would be to get rid of the variables that track the empty row and col. Each Node has its own empty square. You can either move the empty-row/empty-col variables into the Node class, and update them every time the Node's state changes. Or don't add them at all, just add a method that searches `Node.state` for the empty square.